# Hide products with zero or empty price from Woocommerce archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am setting wholesale store with Woocommerce and can't figure out following issue.

I want to auto hide or delate all products, that have price set to zero or if product don't have price at all!

I surf the web and found following code that should do exactly what i need, but i put it in my child theme functions.php file and it is not working for me!

Hide products with the price set to zero in WooCommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'react2wp_hide_products_higher_than_zero' );
function react2wp_hide_products_higher_than_zero( $q ){
   $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_price',
      'value'     => 0,
      'compare'   => '>'
   );
   $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Hide products without price in WooCommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'react2wp_hide_products_without_price' );
function react2wp_hide_products_without_price( $q ){
   $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );
   $meta_query[] = array(
      'key'       => '_price',
      'value'     => '',
      'compare'   => '!='
   );
   $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Source - https://react2wp.com/woocommerce-hide-products-without-price-simple-fix/

I am using Woocommerce 3.4.5 and Flatsome theme (changing theme didn't help too)

How to figure out why code doesn't works?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update** - Added an addition to **auto move to trash** products with zero or empty price

To hide both products that have no price or that have zero price from archive pages as shop, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => '',
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '!='
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

But using something like your first code snippet will do give same result *(prices bigger than zero)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // In frontend only
    if( is_admin() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_price',
        'value'   => 0,
        'type'    => 'numeric',
        'compare' => '>'
    );
    return $meta_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

> **Moving products to trash** *(without deleting them)* that have Zero or empty price.

The following code will update the status of all products that have **Zero** or **empty** price to `trash` **with a very light direct SQL query**.

You need to run it just once each time you want it.

```
// Function that will add products to trash that have Zero price or no price
function auto_add_product_to_trash(){
    global $wpdb;

    $number_of_products_processed = $wpdb->query("
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}posts as a
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS b ON a.ID = b.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS c ON a.ID = c.post_id
        SET a.post_status = 'trash'
        WHERE a.post_status LIKE 'publish' AND a.post_type LIKE 'product'
        AND b.meta_key LIKE '_price' AND c.meta_key LIKE '_sale_price'
        AND ( b.meta_value LIKE '' OR b.meta_value LIKE '0' )
        AND c.meta_value != '0'
    ");
    
    // Return the number of products added to trash
    return $number_of_products_processed;
}

// Execute the function - Run it just once and comment it
auto_add_product_to_trash();
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Now when going to your products in Backend, all products with zero or empty price are in trash. You can review them one by one and delete them easily:
>
> [image]
>
> This way everything is secure as you can restore any product added to trash. If you restore a product, you will have to set its status to published *(restored products get a "draft" status)*

Comment: Thanks for fast response,

Comment: The first code is slow down my site and it's load very long, the second code i tested and it is working on shop page but can you please also take a look on my site https://sperfumes.ru/, i am using plugin to show product as table, and the main goal was to not show zero priced product everywhere, not only on shop page but also in this table at the site hompage

Comment: login - testclient password - testclient

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! I will wait to test it immideatly! Don't know maybe some code conflict with one of my plugins, i am honestly not familiar with coding! Thank again for your help

Comment: @VoskanyanT Added an addition  - Take a look to the last addition that will auto move products to trash that have zero or empty price. Now I will not look to your web site, as when using other third party plugins, you get the limitations on those plugins, and things can be really complicated depending on the plugin.

Comment: Works Great! Thank you very much for your effort and help! Answer accepted!

Answer (score 0):

As as wild guess:
change your `react2wp_hide_products_without_price()` to `'value'=> ''`, to `'value'=> 0,`

Answer (score -1):

you can do it on admin.  Sort by Price - which will put all the priced items together and those without prices together.  Bulk delete the page you are on, and manipulate what you see by changing screen options >  Number of items per page