# Woocommerce functions.php to filter out products with no price

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to write some php to filter out products that have no price listed in the product catalog using the woocommerce_product_is_visible filter.

I tried the following code but it doesn't do anything:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_product_if_zero_price', 10, 2 );
 
function hide_product_if_zero_price( $visible, $product ){
   
   if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) {
      $visible = false;
   }
   return $visible;
}
```

Comment: This will [hide products with zero or empty price from Woocommerce archives pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711148/10497022)